# создать Лист и от листа Стек

Tags: c++, visual-studio, list, стек, data-structures

создать клас Лист и унаследовав от него клас Стек.
в листе только два метода add и remove.
Не знаю з чего начать. Эсть у кого код?
Вопрос в том делать ли на ссылках или на масиве.

Comment: Под ссылками вы имеете в виду указатели ?

Comment: @vegorov, извиняюсь. Сам пишу на Java но дали задание на плюсах. Ума не приложу что да как.

Comment: в плюсах есть и ссылки и указатели. Указатель - это ближе к ссылкам в Java, видимо.

Comment: Напишите классический односвязный список на плюсах. Примеров в интернете полно. Как начнутся конкретные проблемы в Вашем коде - тогда есть смысл постить сюда вопросы с примерами Вашего кода и указанием мест, которые вызывают затруднения. За Вас код здесь не принято писать, такие вопросы обычно минусуют и закрывают.

Comment: @vegorov спасибо за ответ. я вас понял

Comment: Ну и это - классический односвязный список с добавление/удалением с конца по-умолчанию удовлетворяют требованию АДТ (абстрактного типа данных) `стэк`.  Там собственно когда появится класс `список` достаточно будет от него унаследоваться вообще ничего не менять, только обозвать по другому, типа `class Stack: public List{}`. А - вам надо будет добавить метод top() в класс Stack - типа вернуть последний элемент списка (верхний элемент стэка). У вас в классе List по заданию только два метода  - add/remove, не хватает top до стэка

Comment: @vegorov а реалиции у вас нету того о чем вы написали или хотя бы линк на источник

Comment: Я вот вбил с гугл `с++ односвязный список` - и там первая ссылка ведет на реализацию на Си, а вторая - уже на реализацию на C++.  Честное слово, я не врал про `примеров в интернете полно`. Третья ссылка ведёт на очень хорошую реализацию на С++ с использованием шаблонов, четвёртая ссылка ведёт на ответ на ру стэковерфлоу как сделать односвязный список на массиве. Дальше не смотрел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <class T>
class List {
protected:
    struct Node {
        T value;
        T* next;
        Node(T& v = T()) : value(v), next(0) {}
    };
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;        
public:
    List();
    List(const List&);
    List& operator =(const List&);
    ~List();
    void add(const T&);
    void remove(Node*);
};
template <class Tp>
class My_stack : List<Tp> {
public:
    void push(const Tp& v) { add(v); }
    void pop()             { remove(this->tail); }
    Tp& top() const        { return *(this->tail); }
    bool empty() const     { return !(this->head) ; }
    size_t size() const
    {
        if (empty())  return 0;
        size_t sz{};
        for (typename List<Tp>::Node* p = this->head; p; p = p->next)
            ++sz;
    }
};
```

Или погуглив или в SO вы найдете много примеров реализации односвязного списка.  У каждого свой подход. Поняв идею, напишите по своему...

Comment: а можна как-то переделать под int?